# How to create a link to a directory on linux

Tags: linux, shell, command

How to create a link to an existing file or directory using a GNU Linux shell command?

Comment: @jcollum: Probably so... [UnixSE has this similar Q&A for example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/create-a-symbolic-link-relative-to-the-current-directory), but the selected answer here seems a better one.

Comment: ln -s /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages

Answer (score 829, accepted):

Symbolic or soft link (files or directories, more flexible and self documenting)

```
#     Source                             Link
ln -s /home/jake/doc/test/2000/something /home/jake/xxx
```

Hard link (files only, less flexible and not self documenting)

```
#   Source                             Link
ln /home/jake/doc/test/2000/something /home/jake/xxx
```

More information: [man ln](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html)

-----

`/home/jake/xxx` is like a new directory. To avoid *"is not a directory: No such file or directory"* error, as  [@trlkly comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587445/how-to-create-a-link-to-a-directory-on-linux#comment56995976_9587490), use relative path in the target, that is, using the example:

1. `cd /home/jake/`
2. `ln -s /home/jake/doc/test/2000/something  xxx`

Comment: Do note that you have to use a full path for this syntax. I wound up having to use `ln "$(pwd)/relative_path" xxx` in order to get an absolute link for `xxx` using a relative path. Apparently, bash clobbering rules are not expanded for the SOURCE.

Comment: ln -s /home/jake/destination /home/jake/link_name

Comment: 'hard link not allowed for directory' is what my debian says

Comment: @zbig As it says, hard link is files only. For dir, use `ln -s`

Comment: `ln` does not achieve the desired result.  The resulting path is `/home/jake/xxx`, not `/home..../something`.

Comment: As trlkly said, write the full path manually. The "ln" command does not expand even the home directory "~".

Comment: The second file parameter is the link-name, the first one the `target` according to `man ln` I think, Your write that the second arg is the target.

Comment: The soft link to a directory worked if I just left out the trailing slash. The link path didn't need to be relative.

Answer (score 63):

you should use :

```
ln -s /home/jake/doc/test/2000/something xxx
```

Comment: as [trlkly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1802924/trlkly) mentioned as a comment in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9587490/6474744), I had to use the full path for both the source and the link.