# Bash completion to make 'cd' command complete working directories from other running shells?

Tags: bash, cd, completion

I'm trying to write a bash completion that will let me complete directory names that other shells are in.

For example, suppose I have another shell open in `/very/long/path/name`, and I'm currently in a directory that contains subdirs `foo` and `bar`. When I type `cd <Tab>`, I want to see:

```
$ cd <Tab>
foo/  bar/  /very/long/path/name
```

I have this command to produce the list of potential completions:

```
ps -Cbash -opid= | xargs pwdx | cut -d" " -f2 | sort -u | while read; do echo ${REPLY#$PWD/}; done | grep -v "^$"
```

For brevity, I'll write this as `...pipeline...`.

On my system there's a `_cd` function that produces the regular completion:

```
$ complete -p cd
complete -o nospace -F _cd cd
```

I would like to reuse this `_cd` function, because it's nontrivial (~30 lines of code, according to `type _cd`). Bonus points if the solution reuses whatever completion is already defined, whether or not it's based on a function called `_cd`.

I thought the `-C` option to `complete` sounded promising, but I can't get it to work:

```
$ complete -C '...pipeline...' cd
$ cd <Tab>grep: cd: No such file or directory
grep: : No such file or directory
grep: cd: No such file or directory
```

Writing my own wrapper function for `-F`, which appends to the `COMPREPLY` array, also didn't quite work:

```
$ function _cd2() { _cd; COMPREPLY=( ${COMPREPLY[@]} $(...pipeline...) ); }
$ cd <Tab>
foo/  bar/  name/
```

It strips off all the path components except the last. I figure it must be something set up by `_cd` that does this, but I'm not sure how to counteract it.

If I remove the `_cd` call from `_cd2`, I do see the completions, but they don't properly complete partial directory names. If I type `cd /ve<Tab>`, it still shows the full path, without actually completing my command line.

How can I get this to do what I want?

---

Appendix: the full definition of `_cd`:

```
$ type _cd
_cd is a function
_cd () 
{ 
    local cur prev words cword;
    _init_completion || return;
    local IFS='
' i j k;
    compopt -o filenames;
    if [[ -z "${CDPATH:-}" || "$cur" == ?(.)?(.)/* ]]; then
        _filedir -d;
        return 0;
    fi;
    local -r mark_dirs=$(_rl_enabled mark-directories && echo y);
    local -r mark_symdirs=$(_rl_enabled mark-symlinked-directories && echo y);
    for i in ${CDPATH//:/'
'};
    do
        k="${#COMPREPLY[@]}";
        for j in $( compgen -d $i/$cur );
        do
            if [[ ( -n $mark_symdirs && -h $j || -n $mark_dirs && ! -h $j ) && ! -d ${j#$i/} ]]; then
                j+="/";
            fi;
            COMPREPLY[k++]=${j#$i/};
        done;
    done;
    _filedir -d;
    if [[ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        i=${COMPREPLY[0]};
        if [[ "$i" == "$cur" && $i != "*/" ]]; then
            COMPREPLY[0]="${i}/";
        fi;
    fi;
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Looks like your custom `_cd` calls `_init_completion`, `_filedir` and maybe some other functions: what are those functions' definitions?

Comment: Oof, they each call into a handful of yet other functions... I'm on a Ubuntu system, if that helps, so if you have access to one you should be able to dig deeper.

Comment: Sadly, no Ubuntu for me.  CentOS, Gentoo, Arch, Slack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the current match against the list of combined options.  Here's a test script that illustrates the moving parts:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p {my,other}/path/to/{a,b,c}

function _cd() {
    COMPREPLY=( my/path/to/a my/path/to/b );
}
complete -o nospace -F _cd cd

function _cd2() {
    local cur opts;
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}";
    _cd;
    opts="${COMPREPLY[@]} other/path/to/c";        # here we combine options
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur})); # here is the secret sauce
}
complete -F _cd2 cd

complete -p cd
```

The most important points are in the `compgen` portion of `_cd2`: that chooses the most suitable options from the combined set of choices (in `$opts`).

Comment: Huh, even which such a trivial `_cd` function? I hadn't expected that. Interesting indeed...

Comment: @Thomas: Yep.  I think I've figured it out.  Refresh and checkout my edit.

Comment: That's great, it almost works! However, if I substitute the real `_cd`, it doesn't show my nice paths anymore, just the stock ones. Added the definition of `_cd` to the question.

Comment: Ah, `compopt +o filenames` undoes that effect. But now I've run into a wall: for `/v`, `/very/long/path/name` and `/very` are both valid completions, so it only completes `/very`, defeating the purpose. Will need to think more about how I want this to work...

Comment: @Thomas, I'd consider using `//` for your usage-based prefixes, and `/` otherwise -- providing a clean way to distinguish. Granted, `compopt filenames` may still try to complete the former, but it gives you a clear place to start in distinguishing user intent.

Comment: That's a good idea. I ended up just writing a `function ocd() { cd "@$"; }` and using that instead. The good thing about that is that I now have a command called `ocd` :)