# export alias in ~.bash_profile for a path having a filename containing space

Tags: bash

I am trying to add an alias in `bash_profile` in Mac. Actual path of file I am trying to create alias is

```
amar@admin:~/Library/Application Support/com.bohemiancoding.sketch3/Plugins 

$pwd

/Users/amar/Library/Application Support/com.bohemiancoding.sketch3/Plugins
```

I have tried 2 options

**Option # 1**

```
export sketch="/Users/amar/Library/Application\ Support/com.bohemiancoding.sketch3/Plugins"
```

This has error like

```
amar@admin:~$ echo $sketch
/Users/amar/Library/Application\ Support/com.bohemiancoding.sketch3/Plugins
amar@admin:~$ cd $sketch
-bash: cd: /Users/amar/Library/Application\: No such file or directory
```

**Option # 2**

```
export sketch="/Users/amar/Library/Application Support/com.bohemiancoding.sketch3/Plugins"
```

this shows error like

```
amar@admin:~$ echo $sketch
/Users/amar/Library/Application Support/com.bohemiancoding.sketch3/Plugins
amar@admin:~$ cd $sketch
-bash: cd: /Users/amar/Library/Application: No such file or directory
```

Issue is near this file name `Application Support`

Comment: There is a neat option, `shopt -s cdable_vars`, that allows to keep a directory path in a variable, like `export sketch='/path/with space/'`, and then you can use `cd sketch` from anywhere in the filesystem. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) and [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958567/how-to-make-an-alias-for-a-long-path/39839346#39839346).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to quote the variable when you expand it:

```
sketch="/Users/amar/Library/Application Support/com.bohemiancoding.sketch3/Plugins"
cd "$sketch"
```

Quoting is not optional and there's nothing you can do to avoid it.

Comment: yeah, it worked, but why I don't have to specify " " in this case. export flink="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-flink/1.3.2" . here cd $flink also works

Comment: That string doesn't contain any metacharacters like space/*/[]/?

Comment: @AmarjitSingh When you use a variable without double-quotes, the shell splits it into "words" (based on spaces, tabs, and linefeeds), and then tries to expand any wildcards (`*`, `?`, `[]`) it finds into lists of matching filenames. It does not pay attention to escapes or quotes in the variable's value when it does this. Occasionally, this is what you want, but (in my experience) usually not. So of the variable contains (or *might* contain) any of these characters, you should double-quote it.