# How to create a custom tilde-like expansion

Tags: shell, environment-variables, alias

There is a folder `e` that I like to frequent. It is nested in /a/b/c/d/e. I was wondering if there was a way to create an alias for the folder `e` the same way the shell has created an alias for tilde (`~`).

By assigning the imagined alias `@@` to `/a/b/c/d/e`, I would be able to use this in commands such as `rm @@/testfile`.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Something [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839346/7575111) perhaps?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux usage questions should be posted to [unix.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: Let them know which shell in particular you're using. bash, zsh, fish, etc., have more options than plain sh.

Comment: @NullDev this answers my question, thank you. For anyone who wants a similar workflow in zsh, you will need to enable the cd-able-vars option by adding `setopt cdablevars` to your zshrc and then defining the nested path with an export. 

Then, when using this new alias you will then need to preface the exported variable with `$` like so: `rm $gg/test.txt`. This will remove the nested test.txt file as required.