# Any way to achieve this? Relative path usage

Tags: java

I have two types of folder structure.

1. A/B/C/D
2. A/Z/C/D

Is there any way to navigate to D path from A using a single generic relative path approach? Pls provide any java code snippets.

Comment: can't undestand the question. How about B/C/D/ - go to folder D? or you want to access both Ds?

Comment: What do you mean by "*navigate*"?  What have you already tried and why it didn't work? What version of Java you use?  Please provide these and any other relevant details.

Comment: For strcture 1, I can use cd B/C/D. For 2, I can use cd Z/C/D but i want to know is there any possibility to use like cd */C/D?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have two folders with Same name under different directories.

And

you want to create a link (or) short cut to go to one path always to avoid the confusion.

For that you need to create a `link` for that particular folder. Like

```
ln   -s   /A/B/C/D   To-D
```

[More info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587445/how-to-create-a-link-to-a-directory)