# is it possible to commit all selected projects from Eclipse to one github repository

Tags: eclipse, git, github

how is it possible to commit all selected projects from Eclipse to one github repository(as imaged below)?
Currently when I commit my new project to github, a new repository will be created.And I'd like to avoid creating massive number of new repositories.
Thank you in advance!

p.s.I found other related topics for this question, but don't know what I should do exactly.
need your help please.

[image: projects]

Answer (score 0):

There shall be an Eclipse plugin that'll do your git job but I'll tell you a generic solution in case that plugin is not helpful. Well, all these selected projects are directories basically and if they're residing inside the same directory, let say `<dir-1>`, then you can add the remote repo path to `<dir-1>` using `git remote add origin <git-path>` and then add all your directories i.e. projects which will be part of the git repo. Best case would be to create separate branches for each of these projects and then merge those branches to `master` when they reach a logical state without any breaking changes. Now, in case, if all these directories are not residing inside `<dir-1>` then create a symbolic link inside `<dir-1>` to all those projects (possibly with same names) so that whenever the original directories are updated these directories are also changed respectively. Check more about [symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9587490/5644090).